# OBS Capping FPS

Tags: video, streaming, gaming, screen-capture

So I have a 144hz monitor and a new GTX 1070 (so I'm getting nice, buttery smooth FPS in League of Legends, for example), but when I start streaming (or just opening OBS in the form of the new "OBS Studio"), I seem to be getting my FPS capped.

Now League still states that my FPS is up in the 400-800 range, but it's very visibly different from what I know to be 144 FPS, and looks more like it's playing back to me at 60 FPS.

Seems to me that OBS capturing my screen almost stops the screen refresh rate down to what OBS is set to record in terms of the stream FPS. Are my suspicions true? If so, how would I remedy this so that I can keep my good FPS while playing but still have a solid stream for Twitch streaming?

Side note: I can't stream at 144 FPS because Twitch has many problems regarding doing that, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reinstalling OBS to see what happens unless you have all your scenes set up perfectly. If that doesn't work I guess you might have to compromise and stream at the highest possible fps ( 60 or something ).